# RichTextBox DragDrop behaving weirdly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

Ok, so I have a richtextbox and would like to be able to drag drop in it. Inside the drag drop event I would like to perform code that changes the richtextbox text, which in turn activates the text changed event. However, I only want some of the code inside the text changed event to activate so I have a variable block that when true, that code inside of the text changed event will not activate. Here it is:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            richTextBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            richTextBox1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(rtbDragDrop);
            richTextBox1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(rtbDragEnter);
        }
        private bool block;
        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (block) return;
            MessageBox.Show("Text Changed Called");
        }
        private void rtbDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            block = true;
            richTextBox1.AppendText("hello");
            block = false;
        }
        private void rtbDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

        private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            block = true;
            richTextBox1.AppendText("hello");
            block = false;
        }

        private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
```

However, the text changed code is still called. This is because block is set to false before the text changed event could fire for some reason.
However, the part that confuses me the MOST is that the FORM drag drop works just fine (Added with designer). Only the richtextbox drag drop causes this problem. Why?

Comment: Try using different name for block variable for rich textbox. It might be conflict between form and rich textbox drag and drop.

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't work. This still happens even when I don't have the form drag events in place.

Comment: Use `BeginInvoke()` to reset `block`.

Comment: Thank You! That did it. I'm new to stackoverflow, how do you mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't, @VisualUser. However, you can explain and show how you fixed the problem using Jimi's solution in an answer to your own question, and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Jimi has found the fix. It’s to use BeginInvoke to reset block.